# Reference C# code from another project without the .exe available?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, dll, reference

I have a solution with two projects:

- Project A, a large private project
- Project B, a small public project which needs a subset of the functions from A

I'm just getting started on Project B, but I already have a Project (A) which handles many things that will be needed in the new one. I would obviously like to reuse these functions without copying them.

If I add these as a reference in Visual Studio (2012) everything works code wise for Project B, but the generated assembly directory will also contain a functioning copy of Project A.exe.

I need to include my code from Project A without having a compiled .exe file in my output directory. Either by having it as a .dll file or inlined into the main assembly without having to refactor out the relevant parts of Project A into a new class library project. Is this possible?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Would extraction from the large be a suitable solution? If there is functionality this is commonly reused it might be suitable to place these in their own small project as a tools library?

Comment: The cheapest trick would be to rename the .exe to .dll, but this ignores a whole lot of other problems, starting with the solution design. Extracting the logic to a shared assembly would certainly be the way to go.

Comment: Unless you split the relevant code out into its own project, there's no good way to give Project B access to that code without also giving it access to all of Project A.

Comment: @Robert Yeah, I mentioned it briefly in my main post. Although a possibility it would be quite time consuming as the project is quite large (~100k lines in total of which I would reuse about half)

Comment: I think it's just a question of how much time that would save you in the long term and whether that's worth it right now. It may not be worth it for this one project, but what about the other 20 down the road. Just a thought.

Comment: You could also use ILMerge to merge the assemblies, but this still won't prevent someone to pull out the ProjectA stuff you're trying to protect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can try to change the `Application Type` of your "A Project" from `Windows Application` to `Class Library`

After that, compile your "A Project" and you will find the `.dll` in the output directory (instead the `.exe`)

Now that you have the `.dll` you can use it as a reference in your "B Project".

To change the `Application Type` you can visit [this link form MSDN](http://Server%20Class%20Library)

Comment: Please don't use `inline code tags` to highlight random terms, this doesn't increase readability.

Comment: Can you show me the right syntax in this case? Thanks you

Comment: Thank you. I think that will work for my intended application. Do you happen to know of any way to automatically build it as a Class Library without having to set it manually whenever I need to release a "Project B" assembly?

Comment: Unless you change it manually, the Application Type of Project A will always remain "Class Library". If they are in the same solution, as your case, you can modify any line of code from Project A (either Project B) and  when you will compile the solution, Visual Studio will automatically reference the new DLL in your Project B output directory

Comment: @ChewToy - While this will work, how is this different from deploying the ProjectA.Exe?  You'll still be deploying all the code from Project A, it just won't be an .exe.   What does this save you?

Comment: maybe because the final user will not be able to execute Project A?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I'm mostly looking to not have multiple executable files in my program directory as it will be delivered by .zip file (on their request, otherwise I would use an installer and a desktop shortcut or something). And thus run straight from the application directory, and the intended users are not tech savvy in the least and will get confused. Also it deters reverse engineering slightly through obfuscation, although still possible. And ProjectA.exe would not be executable in their environment as it requires various peripheral equipment and would not work for them.